# Парсинг fb2 в markdown java

Tags: java, парсер, markdown, fb2

Появился вопрос конвертации текста из **fb2** в **markdown**. Самый легкий способ который мне приходит на ум это просто использование стандартных функций работы с строками (замена символов/строк через тот же `replace()` т.е. замена тегов fb2 на элементы разметки markdown), но все же хотелось бы услышать другие варианты. Процесс гугления особых результатов не принес т.к. находил только варианты конвертации markdown в fb2.

Comment: Очевиднейший вариант — распарсить любым xml-парсером и отпечатать распарсенное в каком угодно нужном виде

Answer (score 3):

fb2 - это обычный xml документ, но со своей специфичной схемой. Можно использовать ваш способ конвертации, либо определить классы со спецификой формата fb2 (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkknj.html) и прочесть документ, далее определить конвертер, в котором указать правила маппинга элементов формата fb2 в Markdown.

Полезная документация по формату fb2 http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/index.html

Comment: Думаю fb2 проще всего в html сконвертировать, а там уже больше вариантов что с этим делать появятся :)